# Ajax me genera tantos Post como veces refresque un div

Tags: jquery, ajax, post

dias. Tengo el siguiente inconveniento con Fullcalendar.

El caso es que el calendario esta en un:

```
<div id='calendar'></div>
```

**Y tengo un `Select` que cada vez que cambiar renderiza el calendario de la Siguiente manera:**

La funcion `recarga()` renderiza el calendar en el div `id="calendar"`.

**Obvie algunas cosas, pero deje lo necesario para que se entienda correctamente.**

```
$("#selectprofesional").change(function recarga() {

  document.getElementById('calendar').innerHTML = ''

  //Datos necesarios para realizar el post
  idProfesional = $("#selectprofesional").val()
  idEspecialidad = $("#selectespecialidad").val()
  nombreProfesional = $('select[name="selectprofesional"] option:selected').text()
  nombreEspecialidad = $('select[name="selectespecialidad"] option:selected').text()
  idPacientePlan = $("#obraSocialPac").val()

  //Envio el id del profesional y recibo el calendar de ese profesional
  $.ajax({
    url: 'MostrarTurnos',
    type: 'post',
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data: JSON.stringify([{
      'idProfesional': idProfesional,
    }]),

    success: function (data) {
      if (data.Mensaje == 'Correcto') {
        var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
        var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
          plugins: ['dayGrid', 'interaction', 'timeGrid', 'list', 'bootstrap'],
          defaultView: 'timeGridWeek',
          themeSystem: 'bootstrap',   
          slotDuration: '00:10:00',
          slotLabelInterval: '00:10:00',
          eventOverlap: false,
          minTime: "07:00:00",
          maxTime: "20:00:00",
          hour: 'numeric',
          minute: '2-digit',
          locale: 'es',
          omitZeroMinute: false,
          meridiem: 'short',
          businessHours: data.Horarios,

          hiddenDays: [0],

          //Fuente de cada boton
          close: 'fa-times',
          prev: 'fa-chevron-left',
          next: 'fa-chevron-right',
          prevYear: 'fa-angle-double-left',
          nextYear: 'fa-angle-double-right',

          //Botonera superior
          header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'timeGridWeek,listWeek',
          },

          //EVENTOS
          events: data.Turnos,
          overlap: false,
          navLinks: true,


          dateClick: function (info, jsEvent) {
            fecha = new Date(info.dateStr);//convierto el numero en Dato


            // El click en #ConfTur envia al App.py los datos para crear un turno
            //ENVIO DE VARIABLES A APP.PY PARA COMITEAR EL TURNO EN LA BASE DE DATOS

            $("#ConfTur").click(function () {
              console.log('Confirma')
              enviaIdPacPlan = $("#MutPac").val()
              enviaDia = $("#DiaTur").val()
              enviaDesde = $("#DesdeTur").val()
              enviaHasta = $("#HastaTur").val()
              enviaIdEsp = $("#EspecialidadProf").val()
              if (enviaIdPacPlan == null) {
                alert('Seleccione un paciente')
              }
              if (enviaIdEsp == null) {
                alert('Seleccione una especialidad')
              } else {
                guardar = $.ajax({
                  url: 'probando',
                  type: 'post',
                  dataType: 'json',
                  contentType: 'application/json',
                  data: JSON.stringify([{
                    'DiaTur': enviaDia,
                    'IdPacPlan': enviaIdPacPlan,
                    'HorTur': enviaDesde,
                    'HorFtur': enviaHasta,
                    'IdEsp': enviaIdEsp,
                    'IdProf': idProfesional
                  }]),
                  success: function (data) {
                    if (data.Mensaje == 'Correcto') {
                      $("#modalCrearTurno").modal('toggle')
                      $("#confirmacionrecarga").html('Su Turno ha sido guardado correctamente ')
                      $("#mensajedealerta").modal()

                      recarga()//**Cuando recibo la respuesta muestro un par de modales y ejecuto nuevamente la recarga del calendario**
                    }
                  }
                })
              }
            });
          }
        })
      }
    }
  })
})
```

El caso es que el primer turno me lo guarda correctamente, el segundo me lo duplica, el tercero me triplica, y asi sucesivamente, no encuentro solucion. Y no comprendo porque lo hace

Answer (score 2, accepted):

es porque le estas asignando un evento onclick una y otra ves

```
$("#ConfTur").click(function () {
```

debes sacarlo de dentro del onchange o matar el evento onclick anterior agregando esta linea de código sobre la anterior

```
$("#ConfTur").prop("onclick", null).off("click"); // (new line) clean on click events
$("#ConfTur").click(function () {
```

Comment: Funcionó, me salvaste